# How do I declare a 2D array which has to store both int and char values in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have to create an array which has to hold both integer and character values. How do I declare its data type to accommodate both types??

Comment: You can store all `char` values in an `int`

Comment: If either an int or char: union. If both: struct. Though both ints and chars are integer types, with the only difference being their size. What's your use case?

Comment: While not a _2D array_ you can use `std::vector<std::pair<int, char>> v;`. Or a `std::map` maybe.

Comment: `std::vector<std::variant<int, char>> v;`

Comment: What do you mean by both int and char? Do you need to store pairs? Or can each element be either an int or a char?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

**Union:**

```
Union S {   
   int myInt;
   char myChar; 
};
```

or use **boost::variant**

```
variant<int, char> v;
```

Comment: There's also `std::variant` in C++17 if the person asking has a compiler with C++17 support

Comment: The union makes little sense, there"s no way to know what is there.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an array of `int`, and store the `char` values in its cells. A `char` is actually a small integer.